# Internal Engine Blue tint?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I've been rendering a project for about 2 1/2 weeks for now... It's a 600 frame project and this issue started around frame 400. I keep getting these light streaks around my light sources... this is what they look like:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Overview]

And ever since around frame 500, I get these laser-like streaks covering my render window. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Ewww]

I think the ones that started around frame 400 look pretty cool, and that's not as much of an issue, but the ugly ones from frame 500 need to be resolved. These issues don't appear from compositing but appear during the render... Anything on how to resolve this?

Comment: You can uplad images to Blender Stack Exchange directly - just edit your question and click on the image icon on the text editor's header.